# Why I am getting error when I am trying to use virtualenvwrapper.

Tags: 14.04, pip

I have installed virtualenv using pip command:

```
$ pip install --user virtualenv
```

and virtualenwrapper

```
$ pip install --user virtualenvwrapper
```

everything worked fine:

```
$ pip show virtualenvwrapper
Name: virtualenvwrapper
Version: 4.3.2
Location: /home/mukesh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: virtualenv, virtualenv-clone, stevedore
```

I made two directories ".virtenvs" and "Project-Active". I am doing this by following a blog post. Then I have changed my .bashrc file by adding following lines:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Projects-Active
source $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After saving the changes, I sourced the file to make the changes active:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

When I am trying to make a new virtual environment by using following command:

```
$ mkvirtualenv test_env01
```

I am getting error:

```
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path
```

Don't know what should I do now.

Answer (score 5):

I could solve the problem by installing virtualenv via apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

I really don't know the consequences of this, but so far it works for me

Answer (score 4):

I tried to follow the tutorial as well, but it still fails, then had to do it another way:

```
# pip install virtualenv
# pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

After doing so, which command worked indicating where the executable is:

```
which virtualenvwrapper.sh
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

As I understand it in a publication, the virtualenv must be installed via sudo without the --user option.

Answer (score 3):

DO the two steps：

1) `sudo find / -name "virtualenv"`

Then I find the executable file, the path is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv
```

2) Touch a soft link in the or add the path to the `.bash_profile`, I prefer the former:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, following the instructions on some sites will land you in problem. Here's how i did it but first the common mistakes:

```
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

now that's not gonna work for you especially now with 16.04 comes with virtualenv as one of her packages. Some pitfalls is now trying to uninstall it with:

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
```

when you never installed it with admin rights. Instead do:

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

then now install it with the Ubuntu repo (recommended) using:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
sudo apt install virtualenvwrapper
```

**virtualwrapper (user friendly wrappers for the functionality of virtualenv)**
The reason we are also installing [virtualwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) is because it offers nice and simple commands to manage your virtual environments.

```
echo "source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Source virtualenvwrapper in .bashrc

or

open your .bashrc file and add:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/PyProj
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

this will set the location where the virtual environments should live, the location of your development project directories, and the location of the script installed with this package.

now run `workon`
if this is your first time it won't show anything, don't panic. If not, a list of environments, empty, is printed.
run `mkvirtualenv temp`
new environment, *temp* is created and activated.
then run `workon` again
This time, the *temp* environment is included.

Now have fun